# Using a straight sql statement in a progress application

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

What is the syntax to run a straight sql statement in a progress application?

```
  SELECT count(distinct myField2) FROM myTable WHERE myField = myVariable);
```

I've figured out how to do this with a for each but I would still like to run this command. 
Using a for each:

```
def var iTmpCount as int no-undo.
for each myTable no-lock where myField = myVariable break by myField2:
  if first-of (myTable.myField2) then 
    iTmpCount = iTmpCount + 1.
end.
```

Comment: What you're looking for is called an aggregate.  IIRC look into the `ACCUMULATE` function.  Either that or upgrade to using SQL with the JDBC/ODBC drivers. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4GL has an ancient and deprecated implementation of SQL-89.

You can do some simple things successfully.  It is sometimes helpful for an ad-hoc query.

The documentation is limited and, since it is a deprecated feature, it will never be improved or enhanced.

The 4GL is not a SQL tool and the embedded SQL support should not be used.  Don't try to apply SQL thinking to 4GL, you will only regret it.

SQL-92 is supported via the ODBC & JDBC drivers.  But that is outside the 4GL.